# Proof in Propositional Logic of Peirce's Law

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I proove in Propositional Logic (using only the basic axioms of P.L. and not a valuation function like it's used in Propositional Calculus) that :

> $\vdash$ ((($\phi$ $\to$ $\psi$ )$\to$ $\phi$)$\to$ $\phi$)

where $\phi$,$\psi$ are given formulas ?

Comment: excuse my bad writing.. i don't know how to make the symbols apear, if any one can correct this it woulb be lovely.

Comment: Just enclose them between $ signs. Also, use \phi and \psi. Btw, exactly what 'basic axioms' do you refer here?

Comment: This, or all substitution instances of it, just *might be* one of the "basic axioms". It's [Peirce's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce's_law). That link may give you ideas about how to prove it, depending upon what formalism you have in mind... which is unclear. So, same question as @Berci asked: what "basic axioms" do you have in mind?

Comment: You mean $\phi\to(\psi\to\phi)$? as one axiom? (this can't be the only one, I expect a 2), ...) So, A Hilbert-style system.

Comment: basically: 1) $\phi$ $\to$ ($\psi$ $\to$ $\phi$ ) 2) ($\phi$ $\to$ ($\psi$ $\to$ $\omega$ ) ) $\to$ ( ($\phi$ $\to$ $\psi$ ) $\to$ ($\phi$ $\to$ $\omega$)) 3)($\lont$ $\phi$ $\to$ $\lont$ $\psi$) $\to$ (($\lont$ $\phi$ $\to$ $\psi$)$\to$ $\phi$  ) those are what our professor gave us and a couple of lemmas

Comment: and the lemmas are proven by those three axioms and the Mondus Ponens rule.

Comment: @LenaPappa: Do you have Deduction Theorem?  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem)

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco yes we can use the deduction theorem! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*Axioms* :

(A1) $\phi\to (\psi \to \phi)$

(A2) $(\phi → (ψ → ω)) → ((ϕ → ψ) → (ϕ → ω))$

(A3) $(\lnot ϕ → \lnot ψ) → ((\lnot ϕ → ψ) → ϕ)$.

---

With (A1) and (A2) we can prove :

*Lemma 1* : $\vdash (\phi\to \phi)$.

With (A1), (A2) and *Lemma 1* we can prove the:

*Deduction Th* : If $\Gamma$ is a set of formulae and $\phi, \psi$ are formulae, and $\Gamma , \phi \vdash \psi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi$.

Finally, we have to prove :

*Lemma 2* : $\vdash \lnot \phi \to (\phi \to \psi)$

1) $\lnot \phi$ --- premise

2) $\phi$ --- premise

3) $\vdash \phi \to (\lnot \psi \to \phi)$ --- (A1)

4) $\vdash \lnot \phi \to (\lnot \psi \to \lnot \phi)$ --- (A1)

5) $\lnot \psi \to \phi$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

6) $\lnot \psi \to \lnot \phi$ --- from 1) and 4) by *mp*

7) $\psi$ --- from 5), 6) and (A3)

> 8) $\lnot \phi, \phi \vdash \psi$ --- 1), 2) and 7)
>
> > $\vdash \lnot \phi \to (\phi \to \psi)$ --- from 8) by *Ded.Th* twice.

---

Now for the main proof :

1) $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \phi$ --- premise

3) $\vdash \lnot \phi \to (\phi \to \psi)$ --- *Lemma 2*

4) $\phi \to \psi$ --- from 2) and 3) by *mp*

5) $\phi$ --- from 1) and 4) by *mp*

6) $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ \vdash \lnot \phi \to \phi$ --- from 2) and 5) by *Ded.Th*

7) $\vdash \lnot \phi \to \lnot \phi$ --- *Lemma 1*

8) $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ \vdash \phi$ --- from 6), 7) and (A3) by *mp* twice

> > $\vdash ((ϕ → ψ ) → ϕ) → ϕ$ --- from 8) by *Ded.Th*.

Comment: thank you! but how can you use in the main proof step 2) as a premise? we are suppose to use only the formula you type in step 1) as given and all the tautologies..

Comment: @LenaPappa - it is an applcation of *Ded.Th*; from 1)-5) : $(ϕ→ψ)→ϕ, ¬ϕ  \vdash ϕ$, I've derived 6) $(ϕ→ψ)→ϕ \vdash ¬ϕ→ϕ$

Comment: in 4) you use mp on 2) and 3)... but u can't have 2) in the first place... it's not given how can you use it? and its not proven by the axioms! sorry but it seems to me like you are proving { ($(\phi \to \psi) \to \phi)$ , $\lnot\phi$ } $\vdash$ $\phi$ instead of { ($(\phi \to \psi) \to \phi)$ } $\vdash$ $\phi$

Comment: I don't see how you got to step 8.

Comment: @LenaPappa - except for parentheses, it exactly what I've written in my comment above : 1)-5) proves : $(ϕ→ψ)→ϕ,¬ϕ⊢ϕ$ which is $\{ (ϕ→ψ)→ϕ), ¬ϕ \} ⊢ ϕ$. Then applying *Ded.Th* :  "if $Γ, \alpha ⊢ \beta$, then $Γ ⊢ \alpha → \beta$, with as $Γ$ the single formula $(ϕ→ψ)→ϕ$, I've derived in step 6) : $(ϕ→ψ)→ϕ ⊢ ¬ϕ → ϕ$.

Answer (score 0):

Using  form of natural deduction in which implication is left associative:

[image]