# $\vdash_L ((B \longrightarrow C)\longrightarrow B) \longrightarrow B$ Using the Deduction Theorem

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

Trying to deduce $((B \longrightarrow C)\longrightarrow B) \longrightarrow B$ with the the Axioms of Hilbert-Ackerman formal system, but cannot achieve so.

It is only permited to use Deduction Theorem or proven Theorems.

Edit. The tree Axioms are:

1. $\displaystyle A \longrightarrow (B \longrightarrow A)$
2. $\displaystyle (A\longrightarrow (B \longrightarrow C)) \longrightarrow ((A\longrightarrow B) \longrightarrow (A \longrightarrow C))$
3. $\displaystyle (\neg B \longrightarrow \neg A) \longrightarrow ((\neg B \longrightarrow A) \longrightarrow B)$

Comment: What are the exact axioms of the system that you are working with? There are many ‘Hilbert’ systems, but the exact rules make a difference. Can you please add those to your post?

Comment: This is called [Pierce's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law), and many people have asked how to derive it on this site. See, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1618773/655547), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2635168/655547), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4240666/655547).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor that's what i was looking for!!! that was not trivial for me

Comment: It is (I seem to recall) the simplest tautology without any negations which needs an axiom with negations to prove.